# Best practice to share a module between 2 applications

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider I have 2 web services in Python 2.7. 
Both have to use the same module I have developped (and may evolve).

Now, the module's sources are in subfolder of the first application but I would want the second to use is too.

What would be the best practice to share the module between both applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this common module and repackage it as its own independent package, not in either of your web services. Then have the 2 web services (and any future ones) import this as an external module.

And congratulations on thinking in terms of code reuse, and not just doing a quick-and-dirty copy/paste of the common module from web service 1 to web service 2!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By repackage, do you mean it should be installed in site-packages ?

Comment: That is the simplest way, and probably the best way to go for now. But if you want to move these webservices to other machines, it is easy to forget dependencies on modules in site-packages. At that point, make this common module a standalone package and add it to the dependencies in both webservices' configs.